After granting background location permission take the user back to app
On a React Native app, I'm using expo-location to check and request location permissions.
(Android only) First I request foreground location permission and an Android pop up on top of my app is shown. Then at some point I request background location permission and the user is taken to the Location permission screen (Android screen outside my app). So far so good, but when user selects an option, lets say "Allow all the time" it remains on the same screen until user manually navigate back to the app.
Question: Is there any way to take the user back to the app automatically after selecting an option on the Location permission screen?
Note: on iOS both permissions (foreground and background location) are requested from a pop-up so it's not a problem on that platform.

Only way is to use the Accessibility service, but it would be overkill and the user has to make too many steps to give this permission. More than your current state of your app.

Quick answer, no you can't. Your app is in the background at that point.
How I usually handle this is to pop open a dialog right before taking the user to the permission screen. Explain to the user that they are going to be navigated away from your app and explain concisely what you need them to do. Something like "On the following screen choose 'Allow all the time' and use back to return to this app."
This of course is after you've already explained the rationale for why you need such a permission. I like to do this within some fragment text so I'm not bombarding the user with dialogs.
